# Listing project layers in standalone PyQGIS script

Tags: pyqgis, layers, list

I'm trying to load an existing .qgs project and get a list of the layers inside. I seem to be able to open the project, but I can't get the list of layers. I'm a little confused as to the basic PyQGIS syntax, and the cookbook doesn't cover this specific example.

```
from qgis.core import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import QFileInfo


QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(r"C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis-ltr", True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()
# Get the project instance
project = QgsProject.instance()
# Open the project
project.read(QFileInfo(
        r'C:\path\to\project\project.qgs'))
print project.fileName()
# Get the layers in the project
layers = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers()

print layers
qgs.exitQgis()
```

Currently, this just `layers` returns an empty dict, despite the fact that the project exists and has many layers in it.

Comment: I have the same problem in `QGIS 2.18.2` tried steps of OP and @GermánCarrillo. What's OP's version?

Comment: I was using QGIS 2.16.2 on Windows 7x64 at the time. Have since tried on 2.18.2 and still did not work.

Comment: I flagged this question for reopening because the linked question applies to within QGIS, but the solution doesn't work in a standalone Python script

Comment: Have you tried: layers = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().keys()

Comment: Can you try to insert `QgsApplication.processEvents()` right after `project.read`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I also receive an empty dictionary when I run your code but the following works for me which is slightly different:

```
from qgis.core import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import QFileInfo
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
import os

from os.path import expanduser
home = expanduser("~")

QgsApplication( [], False, home + "/AppData/Local/Temp" )
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis", True)
app = QApplication([], True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()

# Get the project instance
project = QgsProject.instance()
# Open the project
project.read(QFileInfo('C:\path\to\project\project.qgs'))
print project.fileName()
# Get the layers in the project
layers = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers()
print layers

QgsApplication.exitQgis()
app.exit()
```

---

*Tested on QGIS 2.18.3 for Windows 7 64-bit.*

[image: Result]

---

---

**Edit:**

The main difference, I believe, between your code and what I used is that you need to  create the QApplication object before creating the QgsApplication. So you would need to replace:

```
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
```

with this:

```
qgs = QApplication([], False)
```

But the QApplication class needs to be imported so we must add the following:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
```

And finally, if you want to do a cleanup, you need to add the following at the end.

```
QgsApplication.exitQgis()
```

---

So you could try using the following code which is more close to your original code:

```
from qgis.core import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import QFileInfo
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication

QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis", True)
qgs = QApplication([], False)
QgsApplication.initQgis()
# Get the project instance
project = QgsProject.instance()
# Open the project
project.read(QFileInfo('C:/path/to/project/project.qgs'))
print project.fileName()
# Get the layers in the project
layers = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers()

print layers
QgsApplication.exitQgis()
```

Comment: This worked on Win7x64 QGIS 2.8.6 32-bit. I'll check other versions later in the week.

Comment: @Joseph, could you explain what's different?

Comment: @raphael - Thanks, I've edited the post to include the main differences ;)

Comment: Also worked on Win7x64 QGIS 2.14.9x64